# How can I reverse DispatcherTimer?

Tags: c#

I need to reverse DispatcherTimer

```
    public TestTimer()
    {
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        StartTimer();            
    }

    private DispatcherTimer Timer;

    private int _seconds;
    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return _seconds; }
        set
        {
            if(value > -1 && value < 61)
                _seconds = value;
        }
    }

    private int _minutes;
    public int Minutes
    {
        get { return _minutes; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 61)
                _minutes = value;
        }
    }

    private int _hours;
    public int Hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 25)
                _hours = value;
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        Timer.Start();
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        Timer.Stop();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Seconds > 59)
        {
            Seconds = 0;
            Minutes++;

            if (Minutes > 59)
            {
                Minutes = 0;
                Hours++;

                if (Hours > 23)
                    Hours = 0;
            }
        }
        Seconds++;

        TimeFormat = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
            Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse" ?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I heed it to show time like 03/12/10 .. 03/12/09 .. 03/12/08 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do or for what purpose.

If you want counting then you can use the `TimerTick` event handler to elapse every second and to count, or more efficiently, use `DateTime.Now` when you start, and subtract `DateTime.Now` when finished to get a `TimeSpan` between them.

If you're counting down, you can use the same approach but subtract the elapsed number of ticks away from your start to get your current countdown value.