# How to show even/odd seconds with DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two text blocks, which show timer's value using `DispatcherTimer`.
I need to update their values each 2 second and one block must show only even seconds, another - only odd seconds.

[image]

**View**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="textTimeMiddle"
        Text="{Binding TestTimer.TimeFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Name="textTimeBottom"
        Text="{Binding TestTimer.TimeFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Model**

```
public class TestTimer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TestTimer()
    {
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        Timer.Start();       
    }

    private DispatcherTimer Timer;

    private string _timeFormat;
    public string TimeFormat
    {
        get { return _timeFormat; }
        set
        {
            _timeFormat = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _seconds;
    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return _seconds; }
        set
        {
            if(value > -1 && value < 61)
            {
                _seconds = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _minutes;
    public int Minutes
    {
        get { return _minutes; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 61)
            {
                _minutes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _hours;
    public int Hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 25)
            {
                _hours = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Seconds > 59)
        {
            Seconds = 0;
            Minutes++;

            if (Minutes > 59)
            {
                Minutes = 0;
                Hours++;

                if (Hours > 23)
                    Hours = 0;
            }
        }
        Seconds++;
        TimeFormat = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
            Hours, Minutes, Seconds);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @RyanWilson How to update values of TextBlocks each 2 second and in one block  show only even seconds, in another - only odd seconds?

Comment: @DimaKozyr the way this code is written, you're asking how to write a format pattern for `ToString()` or `String.Format()`. You could simplify this code a *lot* if you replaced all those calculations with a `Stopwatch` and used its `Ellapsed` property as the actual time value. That's a `TimeSpan` property which already provides properties for minutes, seconds etc. The timer event is only needed to trigger a refresh, nothing more

Comment: @DimaKozyr an even better solution would be to get rid of the `Minute`, `Seconds` and `TimeFormat` properties. Bind to the `Elapsed` property and use the `StringFormat` binding property to specify how to display that timespan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, OP has accepted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56056355/1997232) with simpler approach already, but he didn't learn from it. I wonder what the next question would be.

Comment: Just create two different binding properties and update those accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess your seconds is not exceeding 60 seconds. So this code should work.

```
 int i = 16;//your seconds number here in the place of i
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        string eventextbox = i.ToString(); //your even numbers textbox.text
        //Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("even = " + eventextbox);
    }
    else
    {
        string oddtextbox = i.ToString();//Odd Number textbox.text
       // Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("odd = " + oddtextbox);
    }
```

Comment: I already created second binding property and it works, but still thank you for your answer